# Difference between Enterprise mobility security MFA and O365 multifactor authentication

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, office-365

Can anyone provide me exact differences between enterprise mobility security multifactor authentication(MFA) VS O365 MFA  ?

And also how check which users has what kind of mFA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Enterprise mobility security multifactor authentication is considered `Azure Multi-Factor Authentication full version`.

- `Azure Multi-Factor Authentication` is a full version that offers the richest set of capabilities.

  - It provides additional configuration options via the Azure classic portal, advanced reporting, and support for a range of on-premises and cloud applications.
  - Comes as part of Azure Active Directory Premium and Enterprise Mobility Suite, and **can be deployed either in the cloud or on premises**.
- `Multi-Factor Authentication for Office 365` version works exclusively with Office 365 applications and is managed from the Office 365 portal. So administrators can now help secure their Office 365 resources with two-step verification. This version is part of an Office 365 subscription.

**Differences between Azure Multi-Factor Authentication and Multi-Factor Authentication for Office 365**

[image]

**To check the MFA Status for an Office 365 User?**

User Office 365 PowerShell to run the following cmdlet.

**Script**

```
$ThisUSer = Get-msoluser -UserPrincipalName "UserPrincipalName" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty StrongAuthenticationRequirements
$ThisUser.State
```

For more Details check [Azure Multi-Factor Authentication](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/multi-factor-authentication/multi-factor-authentication#how-to-get-azure-multi-factor-authentication)

Comment: Thanks for the info. Do you where we can check O365 MFA under admin center?                                                                                                                Do I need to navigate to active users and then check for any particular user and there I need to click on "Manage multifactor authentication" ?   is this O365 MFA or else Azure MFA?

Comment: your steps are correct, if you already enabled MFA in office 365 you can -Sign-in to the Office 365 Portal > Navigate to the Office 365 admin center > Select users and groups > Active Users >Manage multifactor authentication > here you can find list of users as display name, User name, Multi-Factor Authentication Status in this column you can check it's enabled or disabled , and it's O365 MFA version.

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you for your time and info. Now I am clear about different MFA's